# How to programmatically move, copy and delete files and directories on SD?

Tags: android, file, directory, copy, move

I want to programmatically move, copy and delete files and directories on SD card. I've done a Google search but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Use standard Java I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get to the root of external storage (which, on some devices, is an SD card).

Comment: These copy the contents of files but don't really copy the file - i.e. filing system metadata not copied... I want a way to do this (like shell `cp`) to make a backup before I overwrite a file. Is it possible?

Comment: Actually the most relevant part of the standard Java I/O, java.nio.file, is unfortunately not available on Android (API level 21).

Comment: @CommonsWare: Can we access private files from SD pragmatically? or delete any private file?

Comment: @SaadBilal: An SD card is usually [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), and you do not have arbitrary access to files on removable storage via the filesystem.

Comment: with the release of android 10 scoped storage became the new norm and all Methods of doing operations with files has also changed, the java.io ways of doing will no longer work unless you add "RequestLagacyStorage" with the value "true" in your Manifest the Method Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is also depricated

Comment: This answer is not usable anymore in 2021.

Answer (score 174):

set the correct permissions in the manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

below is a function that will programmatically move your file

```
private void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }


        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

            // write the output file
            out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();  


    } 

         catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
          catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

To Delete the file use

```
private void deleteFile(String inputPath, String inputFile) {
    try {
        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To copy

```
private void copyFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }


        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

            // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
            out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;        

    }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
            catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the permissions in the manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Also, don't forget to add a slash at the end of inputPath and outputPath, Ex: /sdcard/ NOT /sdcard

Comment: i tried to move but i cant.this is my code moveFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),myfile,      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/CopyEcoTab/" );

Comment: Depending on how you use this method, you may not require `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` so make sure you don't add this permission unnecessarily.

Comment: Very helpful, I suggest just dropping this code into a static `FileHelper` class and making your life easier. Thanks

Comment: File is moved but not its metadata, especially lastmodified date is changed

Comment: This below permission is also required from android M <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Also, don't forget to execute these on a background thread via AsyncTask or a Handler, etc.

Comment: Good contribution user469020. Made some edits. Must be weary of Pokemon exception handling ;)  See number 2 of https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/

Comment: @DanielLeahy How to make sure that the file has been copied successfully and then only delete the original file?

Comment: @DanielLeahy What should we pass inside *inputFile* while using *moveFile* because i am giving *fileName* at that point and it's always giving me *FileNotFoundException*. Can you please guide through that ?

Comment: Don't forget to prompt the user for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: `[input / output]Path + File.separator + inputFile` if you don't want to use `new File([input / output]Path, inputFile)` or you end up with some amalgamation of the directory and file name in the folder above where it should be moved.

Answer (score 153):

Move file:

```
File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/kaic1/imagem.jpg");
File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/kaic2/imagem.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: A heads up; "Both paths be on the same mount point. On Android, applications are most likely to hit this restriction when attempting to copy between internal storage and an SD card."

Comment: `renameTo` fails without any explanation

Comment: Strangely, this creates a directory with the desired name, instead of a file. Any ideas about it? The File 'from' is readable, and both of them are in the SD card.

Answer (score 39):

Function for moving files:

```
private void moveFile(File file, File dir) throws IOException {
    File newFile = new File(dir, file.getName());
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    try {
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
        inputChannel.close();
        file.delete();
    } finally {
        if (inputChannel != null) inputChannel.close();
        if (outputChannel != null) outputChannel.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What modifications this needs to COPY the file?

Comment: @BlueMango Remove line 10 `file.delete()`

Comment: This code won't work for big file like 1 gb or 2 gb file.

Comment: @Vishal Why not?

Comment: I guess @Vishal means that copying-and-deleting a large file requires a lot more disk space and time than moving that file.

Answer (score 24):

**Delete**

```
public static void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

 if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
    for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
        deleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();

    }
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/android-how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content) link for above function.

**Copy**

```
public static void copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
    throws IOException {

if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
    if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
        targetLocation.mkdir();
    }

    String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

        copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
    }
} else {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

    // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}

}
```

**Move**

move is nothing just **copy the folder one location to another** then **delete the folder** thats it

**manifest**

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Tried in API 25 to 29. Used  for migrating my files from top level storage to app directory to implement scoped storage.

Answer (score 13):

1. Permissions:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
2. Get SD card root folder:

   ```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   ```
3. Delete file: this is an example on how to delete all empty folders in a root folder:

   ```
   public static void deleteEmptyFolder(File rootFolder){
       if (!rootFolder.isDirectory()) return;

       File[] childFiles = rootFolder.listFiles();
       if (childFiles==null) return;
       if (childFiles.length == 0){
           rootFolder.delete();
       } else {
           for (File childFile : childFiles){
               deleteEmptyFolder(childFile);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Copy file:

   ```
   public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
       FileInputStream var2 = new FileInputStream(src);
       FileOutputStream var3 = new FileOutputStream(dst);
       byte[] var4 = new byte[1024];

       int var5;
       while((var5 = var2.read(var4)) > 0) {
           var3.write(var4, 0, var5);
       }

       var2.close();
       var3.close();
   }
   ```
5. Move file = copy + delete source file

Answer (score 7):

**Copy file using Square's [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio):**

```
BufferedSink bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(destinationFile));
bufferedSink.writeAll(Okio.source(sourceFile));
bufferedSink.close();
```

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin you can use copyTo() extension function,

```
sourceFile.copyTo(destFile, true)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().getAbsolutePath()+"/kaic1/imagem.jpg");
File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/kaic2/imagem.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: [File.renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) works only on the same file system volume. Also you should check result of renameTo.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Guava, you can use [Files.move(from, to)](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/io/Files.html)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @LarsH I fixed the link to Guava JavaDoc.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
     * Copy the local DB file of an application to the root of external storage directory
     * @param context the Context of application
     * @param dbName The name of the DB
     */
    private void copyDbToExternalStorage(Context context , String dbName){

        try {
            File name = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
            File sdcardFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "test.db");//The name of output file
            sdcardFile.createNewFile();
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(name);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(sdcardFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception" , e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving file using kotlin. App has to have permission to write a file in destination directory.

```
@Throws(FileNotFoundException::class, IOError::class)
private fun moveTo(source: File, dest: File, destDirectory: File? = null) {

    if (destDirectory?.exists() == false) {
        destDirectory.mkdir()
    }

    val fis = FileInputStream(source)
    val bufferLength = 1024
    val buffer = ByteArray(bufferLength)
    val fos = FileOutputStream(dest)
    val bos = BufferedOutputStream(fos, bufferLength)
    var read = fis.read(buffer, 0, read)
    while (read != -1) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, read)
        read = fis.read(buffer) // if read value is -1, it escapes loop.
    }
    fis.close()
    bos.flush()
    bos.close()

    if (!source.delete()) {
        HLog.w(TAG, klass, "failed to delete ${source.name}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move File or Folder:

```
public static void moveFile(File srcFileOrDirectory, File desFileOrDirectory) throws IOException {
    File newFile = new File(desFileOrDirectory, srcFileOrDirectory.getName());
    try (FileChannel outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel(); FileChannel inputChannel = new FileInputStream(srcFileOrDirectory).getChannel()) {
        inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
        inputChannel.close();
        deleteRecursive(srcFileOrDirectory);
    }
}

private static void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : Objects.requireNonNull(fileOrDirectory.listFiles()))
            deleteRecursive(child);
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Xamarin Android**

```
public static bool MoveFile(string CurrentFilePath, string NewFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (var f = new File(CurrentFilePath))
        using (var i = new FileInputStream(f))
        using (var o = new FileOutputStream(NewFilePath))
        {
            i.Channel.TransferTo(0, i.Channel.Size(), o.Channel);
            f.Delete();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}

public static bool CopyFile(string CurrentFilePath, string NewFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (var i = new FileInputStream(CurrentFilePath))
        using (var o = new FileOutputStream(NewFilePath))
            i.Channel.TransferTo(0, i.Channel.Size(), o.Channel);

        return true;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}

public static bool DeleteFile(string FilePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (var file = new File(FilePath))
            file.Delete();

        return true;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To move a file this api can be used but you need atleat 26 as api level -

[move file](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

But if you want to move directory no support is there so this native code can be used

```
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.File;

    public class FileModule {

    public void moveDirectory(String src, String des) {
    File srcDir = new File(src);
    File destDir = new File(des);
     try {
        FileUtils.moveDirectory(srcDir,destDir);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Exception" , e.toString());
      }
    }

    public void deleteDirectory(String dir) {
      File delDir = new File(dir);
      try {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(delDir);
       } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("Exception" , e.toString());
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this folder with file path & destination path

```
public void copyFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);
    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```