# For loop causing android app to crash

Tags: android

i'm having trouble figuring out why my app is crashing every time i open it. It's only when I uncomment the for loop.

I'm using this idea here to copy files from one directory to another

[How to programmatically move, copy and delete files and directories on SD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd)

however this part (i tried both this way and the same way as in the link above, using children string, etc)

```
for (File file : files)
{
    CopyFile(file, target);
}
```

keeps causing my application to crash. I tried commenting out just this part and the app runs fine (it doesnt copy anything however as its not accessing a file)

Any ideas?

```
    private void CopyFile(File source, File target) throws IOException {



    if (source.isDirectory()){

        File[] files = source.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            CopyFile(file, target);
        }

    } else {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();

    }
```

Comment: Do you have the permissions to read and write from external storage?

Comment: Could be for a number of reasons. Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and the `Class` where the `for` loop resides.

Comment: Yes i have write permissions from external storage. I do not have any read/write permissions from root directory however, which is where im trying to access the file from (/data/data/ to be exact)

I edited the original post

Comment: No exception, No help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read anything in /data/data except from subdirectories controlled by your app.

```
/data/data/*packagename*/files
```

is the path returned by Context.getFilesDir()

```
/data
```

is the path returned by Environment.getDataDirectory().

Where *exactly* do you expect the files to be, and how did they get there originally?

Comment: Really? Interesting. How do things like root explorer and such do it then?