# Android: copying files from one directory to another

Tags: android, file, directory, copy

I am working on copying one file (the temp audio file) from source folder to the destination folder as TT_1A using the following code with the use of apache commons library.

### Code:

```
button1_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TT/tt_temp.3gp";
            File source = new File(sourcePath);

            String descPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TT/tt_1A.3gp";
            File desc = new File(descPath);
            try 
            {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

### Apache Commons:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

### Question:

I have used the `FileUtils` function so as to copy the temp file and paste to the desc folder as TT_1A. Yet logcat reports error with the following details:

```
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at com.abc.abc.TT_details_canton$14.onClick(TT_details_canton.java:575)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
10-17 00:41:04.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27450):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have stucked by this for the whole night. Are there ways to copy files??

Comment: Did you mark the commons jar as "export" in your classpath? Seems like it's not being excluded in the apk.

Comment: sorry I find a terrible mistake, after amending the code as  FileUtils.copyFile(source, desc); it now performed as intented. Still Many thanks for your help!

Comment: [To move a file, this might help:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24841162/6482996)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It runs good after amended in the following way:

```
    button1_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TongueTwister/tt_temp.3gp";
            File source = new File(sourcePath);

            String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TongueTwister/tt_1A.3gp";
            File destination = new File(destinationPath);
            try 
            {
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is FileUtils ?  @pearmak

Comment: @APOORVADOSHI [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html) is Apache commons io package. To use it, you have to add commons-io.jar into your project.

Comment: FileUtils solved the problem like a charm , also it copies entire directory just pass the destination directory and source directory , it will copy the entire directory into the new directory

Comment: commons-io android gradle dependancy

 compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

Comment: FileUtils.copyFile() functions makes one extra copy of file in DCIM folder!

Answer (score 6):

In API level 29, android added **FileUtils** class, which has copy function.

Use this code to copy your file:-

```
public void copyFile(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(source), new FileOutputStream(destination));
}
```

If Android Studio does not find **FileUtils** class, that means your compileSdkVersion is lower than 29, in this case, you have to upgrade your compileSdkVersion.

For upgrading, go to your app-level build.gradle file and replace the old **compileSdkVersion** with 29

Like this

```
compileSdkVersion 29
```

For more info about *FileUtils* class, visit Android Developer Website
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUtils

Comment: You have to increase minSdkVersion to 29, not compileSdkVersion.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210629_175744.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Make sure the read write permissions are given before this call