# How to make the code for Android File moving in the SDcard?

Tags: android

I will make rooting-Tool. But I need the File move Source please tell me about it(code)?...
I'm so sorry but Answer to me please.

```
**`" How to make the Code for Android File Moving in the SDcard "`**
```

Comment: You want to write code for creating a file in `sdcard`?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal NO NO if the file in /sdcard/download/abc.txt ,and press the button this file move to /sdcard/abc.txt

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11327789/1979347

Comment: Where the actual code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically move, copy and delete files and directories on SD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move your file from one location to another you can use this:

```
private void moveFile(String inputPath, String outputPath) {

    System.out.println(inputPath);
    System.out.println(outputPath);



    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        // create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File(outputPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

        // write the output file
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath).delete();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("File not found exception", fnfe1.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Other Exception", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

To call this method you can do this:

```
moveFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/abc.txt", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/abc.txt");
```

Also you need to give writing permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Forgot to add write permissions?