# How to copy files in Android Storage?

Tags: android, copy

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I am trying to copy .jpg file to and from in Storage folders.

```
  try {
        Process c = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dd if="+path+ 
        "of="+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/1.jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

path contains the exact image location in storage ! But it doesn't work. It can't copy the image to another folder of storage. Please kindly help me to solve this in every possible way! Thank you.

Comment: do you have the right permissions? What is you exception

Comment: yes .. I added right permission ! updated in question . thank you.

Comment: Please, It is my 2nd java activity. If permission support for 2nd activity added in manifest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try {
        String cmd="dd if="+path+" of="+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/1.jpg";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd+"\n");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ... it works definitely . Best Copying among the other library project codes !

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me sometimes and I use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: please let me know Is there any other way to copy files in storage ?

Comment: Have you tried previous answers? Here it has good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd

Comment: Thank you so much for reference ! now trying to accept it :) . Thanks !