# Delete files from application directory folder in Android?

Tags: android

I created folder inside application directory.

```
File dir = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir().getParent() + File.separator + "Image directory");
```

in that again i created folder for specify contents

```
File dir1 = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir().getParent() + File.separator + "Image directory" + File.separator+ "Image 1");
```

Inside that I am going to storage images. Images are stored and accessed.

I want to delete all images which are stored at dir1 location.

I tried

```
if(dir1.isDirectory())
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dir1.length; j++)
    {
        File file = new File(dir1, dir1[j]);
        //file.canExecute();
        file.delete(); 
    }
}
```

`file.delete();`  returns false each time.

I added permissions in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

Comment: you also need to provide extension like `Image1.jpg`. Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd)

Comment: Yes that is listed in for loop.

Comment: I am at internal storage. in application directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `file.delete` method you have used `bundle` don't know where did that came from.

Below code will delete all files in your `Image Directory`

```
File dir1 = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir().getParent() + File.separator + "Image directory" + File.separator+ "Image 1");
if (dir1 .isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir1 .list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir1 , children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

Make sure you have permission for writing in external memory, which you already have

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```