# Result of .renameTo() is ignored

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ftp4j

I am trying to upload a file via FTP, but before it is uploaded it has to be renamed to the input of 2 editText's. To do this i use the following code:

```
public FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    public void upload_klik (View view) {
        EditText week_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.week_edit);
        EditText pagina_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pagina_edit);
        String w_val = week_text.getText().toString();
        String p_val = pagina_text.getText().toString();
        upload_task up = new upload_task();
        up.execute(w_val, p_val);
    }

    protected class upload_task extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String w = params[0];
            String p = params[1];

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String ret = "Done!";
            if(!bundle.isEmpty()) {
                String afdeling_url = bundle.getString("afdeling_url", "DKW/");
                String afdeling_preFix = bundle.getString("afdeling_preFix", "dkw");
                String locatie_url = bundle.getString("locatie_url", "/delf_wend/");

                String new_fileName = afdeling_preFix +"_" + "w" + w + "_" + "p" + p + ".jpg";

                System.out.println(new_fileName);

                File f = new File(foto_path);
                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File to = new File(sdcard, new_fileName);
                f.renameTo(to);

                if(f != null) {

                    try{
                        client.setPassive(true);
                        client.setAutoNoopTimeout(30000);
                        client.connect(FTP_HOST, 21);
                        client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
                        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                        System.out.println(locatie_url + afdeling_url);
                        client.changeDirectory(locatie_url + afdeling_url);
                        client.upload(to);

                        restart();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        try {
                            client.disconnect(true);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

But when i try to uplaod it Logcat gives me this:

```
09-09 16:33:17.794  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader I/System.out﹕ slag_w11_p222.jpg
09-09 16:33:17.994  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader I/System.out﹕ /delf_wend/SLAG/
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /slag_w11_p222.jpg
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2577)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.upload(FTPClient.java:2457)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader.upload$upload_task.doInBackground(upload.java:154)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader.upload$upload_task.doInBackground(upload.java:119)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

i narrowed the problem to to thwe function `f.renameTo(new_fileName)`, it says the result of calling this method is ignored. But why is it ignored? And is there a way around this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It is ignored because you're not doing `boolean result = f.renameTo(to);` but this doesn't compromise the functionality of your code. If your server is receiving the file, I wouldn't worry about the warning.

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti Look at the logcat log, it cant find the file to upload :/

`09-09 16:33:18.024  23674-25966/nl.knapper_development.jrw_uploader W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /slag_w11_p222.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

the error is pretty straight forward is it's all documented:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

> Many failures are possible. Some of the more likely failures include:
>
> - Write permission is required on the directories containing both the source and destination paths.
> - Search permission is required for all parents of both paths.
> - Both paths be on the same mount point. On Android, applications are most likely to hit this restriction when attempting to copy between internal storage and an SD card.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

> Thrown when a file specified by a program cannot be found

I'm betting that if you check if the file exist with the code:

```
if(f.exists()){
```

you'll find out that `foto_path` is not an existing file, or maybe you should check that `foto_path` is also inside `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

If it's not in the same mount point you have to copy the file over (with the new name) instead of just renaming.

Comment: Oke, i see, i tried some things and i have determined i cant select files which are from my sdcard.  it than prints "/storage/extSdcard/...." but when i select a photo from my downloads folder, not located on my Sdcard it says "/storage/emulated/0/...." these files do upload, so what is it i am doing wrong? you mentioned moving the files?

Comment: If one file is on the device memory (16GB or 32GB for most devices) and the other on the SD-card, `renameTo()` will fail. That's the 3rd bullet poing on my answer copied from the docs. On the following StackOverflow answer you can see how to copy the file. This is different from your approach is it will physically move every byte of the file, one by one to the destination file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29717446/906362 . Your approach literally just renames the file. Copy is a much slower process but it can be done across different mount point.

Answer (score 0):

RenameTo renames the actual file, it doesn't change the File object. If you called .exists() you'd find the new file exists and the old one doesn't.

This is because the File class represents abstract paths rather than actual files on a file system. The idea is that File.renameTo gives a new name to a file system entry at the given path; it does not change the path itself.