# When I run app in android studio app store in internal memory.after moving also it doesn't move to sd card

Tags: android, installation, store, internal

I'm developing an Android app.when i run app in android studio app store in internal memory.after moving also it doesn't move to sdcard and I am not able to install it in the SD Card. This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.clc.encyclopedia" android:versionCode="32"
        android:versionName="23.0" android:installLocation="auto">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

So I don't have any errors about the option installLocation, but at the moment of installing the app, my mobile installs it in the internal memory.

I also have these as permissions, I put it just in case it can give some clues:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I tried a lot but couldn't find the exact reason.Please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your phone SD card have enough space for this application. if have enough space, try: 
android:installLocation="preferExternal".

Comment: yes my sdcard have enough space for this application.i tried both preferExternal and auto aslo.but it doesn't work

Comment: It could be device specific or mounting sd card issue. Have you tried it on any other device?

Comment: yes i aslo tried it in different device.but not able to move app and app data in sdcard.Can i able to move it programmatically ?

Comment: app can move to sdcard but in sdcard it doensn't show where it is.

Comment: App installed in SD Card are saved in encrypted form, you can not access them directly. I think this is to protect paid apps.

Comment: i also want to move app data.how is its possible?

Comment: you can programatically move files to sd card.Go through this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd]

Comment: But if you move your app data to somewhere else it could be inaccessible to your app.

Comment: how do i get path of external memory?