# Cant point to this path /storage/emulated/0/Download/ phone storage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, directory, filepath

I am downloading and Image on the Phone storage and it goes to the folder called `DOWNLOAD` (The folder is on the root of the Phone Storage director).

Am using this code to see the video :

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/NewVisionAR/" + "test.mp4");
```

the video is stored successfully in the `DOWNLOAD` folder, however when I try to get the path of the Video it's null, I use the code below :

```
 var videoLink = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/NewVisionAR/test.mp4
```

But it points to null, I tried to print out its path and it's different, it points to this :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.shliama.augmentedvideotutorial/files/Download/NewVisionAR/
```

and it's null.

The path I want to point to is :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/NewVisionAR
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Use getExternalStorageDirectory() instead.

Answer (score 0):

[How to programmatically move, copy and delete files and directories on SD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd)
You may need "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission