# Is there any way to paste image file ( Uri form ) from clipboard to notepad app in android

Tags: android, uri, clipboard, clipboardmanager

Is there any way to paste **image file** from clipboard to **notepad** app in android. Notepad allow only text to paste from clipboard, but I have image file (Uri Format) in clipboard to paste in notepad app.

If I am trying to paste in Notepad, i got a message that **Not a valid data to paste**.

Is there any system flag that we need to enable/disable to avoid the data type and paste image to notepad  or any other third party app other than image viewer app.

Comment: You copy the file by [conventional I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178168/how-to-programmatically-move-copy-and-delete-files-and-directories-on-sd). What notepad are you talking about is it your app or others?  If its a 3rd party app then it depends on the app how it handles to URI. Usually when you upload a file you use its Path.

Comment: It is unclear if you want to paste an image or an image file or an uri or just a content scheme.

Comment: i want to paste an uri ( ClipType.item ) from clipboard on desktop or any other app.